# REAL ESCAPE STRING IN ORACLE

Tags: oracle

To escape ' quotes for MySQL database, we use mysql_real_escape_string.
What if i wish to do it for Oracle database in PHP ?

Solutions that I found:

1. `''` (double quotes)
2. `q[$string]`

Comment: Don't use it at all. Use parameter placeholders in your SQL statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1509264

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 sounds wrong (maybe you think right, but wrote wrong); it is not double quotes `"`, but two consecutive single quotes `''`.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> select
  2    'I''m Little O''Foot'    option_1,
  3    q'[I'm Little O'Foot]'   option_2
  4  from dual;

OPTION_1          OPTION_2
----------------- -----------------
I'm Little O'Foot I'm Little O'Foot

SQL>
```

Whichever option you choose, it'll work. The second one is easier to handle because you might get lost when there are way too many single quotes in a string.

Yet another, 3rd option, is to concatenate `CHR(39)` (which is a single quote character); it can be useful in tools which don't support the q-quoting mechanism (such as old Forms Builders):

```
SQL> select
  2    'I' || chr(39) || 'm Little O' || chr(39) || 'Foot'   option_3
  3  from dual;

OPTION_3
-----------------
I'm Little O'Foot

SQL>
```